# Tracking rotating Ads with Google Tag Manager

Tags: google-analytics, advertising, event-tracking, google-tag-manager, regular-expression

So at the moment we have our ads setup using event tracking in Google Analytic (Universal) and they are implemented in this format:

```
<a href="example.com" onclick="ga('send', 'event', 'Banner Ad - Top', 'Click','Ad Title - (588x88)',1.00, {'nonInteraction': 1});"target="_blank"><img src="example.com/ads/ad_588x88.jpg" alt=""></a>
```

I would like to track these ads by position if possible because we have ads from same vendors displayed in multiple positions.

I am trying to wrap my brain around how I can implement something like this in Google Tag Manager. I assume this will involve some advanced rules with RegEx? Is it something that can be passed through the dataLayer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could add `data-`attributes to your ad link if you are using HTML5:

```
<a href="example.com" class="someclass" data-adposition="Banner Ad - Top" data-adnamesize="Ad Title - (588x88)" data-advalue="1.00" ><img src="example.com/ads/ad_588x88.jpg" alt=""></a>
```

Then add a new tag in Google Tag Manager for catching clicks on this kind of links (identified by "someclass" as an example). `Tag name`: Whatever-you-want-to-name-it; `Tag Type`: `Custom HTML Tag`.
Using JQuery you can extract `data-`attributes and pass them as parameters to `ga` function. Insert this snippet into `HTML` textbox. Obviously, you'll need to adjust the snippet as you need, based on what you use as `class` and `data-`attributes names.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $( document ).delegate( "a.someclass", "click", function() {
        try{
                ga('send',
                    'event',
                    $(this).data('adposition'), //Event Category
                    'click', //Event action
                    $(this).data('adnamesize'), //Event Label
                    $(this).data('advalue'), //Event value
                    {'nonInteraction': 1}
                );
        }catch(err)
        {
            //do something if you need
        }
    });

});
</script>
```

Then add a `Firing Rule` that fires on every single page of your site, assuming you have those kind on links every where. Such rule should be like this

```
{{url}}    matches regex     .*
```

### Update: Using GTM Link Click Listener

Assuming your links have data-attributes as my example above, you can do something like this:

#### Set up GTM Link Click Listener###

Add a new **Tag**.
Set **Tag Name** to whatever you want, maybe `Link Click Listener`.
Set **Tag Type** to `Link Click Listener`.
Add a **Firing rule** for all pages.

[image: New Tag Link Click Listener]
[image: Firing Rule for Link Click Listener]
[image: Link Click Listener Tag]

#### Set up click event tracking for your ad links

Add a new **Tag**.
Set **Tag Name** to whatever you want, maybe `Ad Links Click`.
Set **Tag Type** to `Google Analytics` => `Universal Analytics` or `Classic Google Analytics`, depends on what version you're using.
Insert your **Web Property Id**.
Set **Track Type** to `Event`; for **Event Tracking Parameters** you'll need to add macros to grab info from your ad links and set them into **Event**'s parameters.

For event **Category**:
Click on the brick icon, then select `New macro`.
Set **Macro Name** to something like `Ad Link Position`.
Set **Macro Type** to `Custom Javascript`.
Insert this code into **Custom Javascript** textbox:

```
function(){
  return {{element}}.dataset.adposition;
}
```

For event **Action** set whatever you want, maybe `click`.

For event **Label**:
Click on the brick icon, then select `New macro`.
Set **Macro Name** to something like `Ad Link Name - Size`.
Set **Macro Type** to `Custom Javascript`.
Insert this code into **Custom Javascript** textbox:

```
function(){
  return {{element}}.dataset.adnamesize;
}
```

For event **Value**:
Click on the brick icon, then select `New macro`.
Set **Macro Name** to something like `Ad Link Value`.
Set **Macro Type** to `Custom Javascript`.
Insert this code into **Custom Javascript** textbox:

```
function(){
  return {{element}}.dataset.advalue;
}
```

Maybe you don't want clicks to those ad links count as an interaction, then set event **Non-interaction** to `true`.

[image: Ad Links Click]

[image: Macro with Custom Javascript]

And here comes the magic, chain `Ad Links Click` to `Link Click Listener`:
Add a new **Firing Rule** for `Ad Links Click` tag.
Set **Rule Name** to something like `Ads GTM Link Click Event`.
Add a new **Condition** set `{{event}}`   `equals`   `gtm.linkClick`.
Add a second **Condition** set `{{element classes}}`   `equals`   `someclass`.

[image: Ads GTM Link Click Event]

Comment: Can't I just create link click listener and then create a custom HTML tag that include the dataLayer push of the event?

Comment: @dasickle Sure, you can use GTM Link Click Listener for firing GA Events when clicking any link. The important thing is to "grab", from somewhere, data to be passed as parameters to GA Event.

Comment: YOU ROCK MAN! Thanks a bunch for the examples. I am finally starting to make sense of how GTM works. The snapshots with the step by step really helped. Let me see if I can set if I could setup some events for other thing on my own using your example. If not I'll post again.

Comment: @dasickle You're welcome, it's great to know my answer helped you.

Comment: I was able to set most of my events up. One is giving be trouble. I posted the question http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/67139/track-subscription-form-that-redirects-to-an-external-url-with-google-tag-manage