# Track subscription form that redirects to an external URL with Google Tag Manager

Tags: google-analytics, forms, event-tracking, google-tag-manager

I have a Gravity Form subscription form that I am currently tracking by triggering an even on the confirmation page using Google Tag Manager. However, very soon this form will redirect to a page on a different domain with a few parameters passed in the url. This means I would have to track the event on submit instead. I have tried the Form submit listener, click listener and link click listener and nothing seems to work. I think I might be grabbing the wrong id/class. I also want to make sure that the event only gets triggered after the form has been validated. Below is the complete form code:

```
<div class="gf_browser_ie gf_browser_ie8 gform_wrapper" id="gform_wrapper_1">
<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="gform_1" action="/">
    <div class="gform_body">
        <ul id="gform_fields_1" class="gform_fields top_label description_below">
            <li id="field_1_2" class="gfield">
                <label class="gfield_label" for="input_1_2">Name</label>
                <div class="ginput_container">
                    <input name="input_2" id="input_1_2" type="text" value="" class="large" tabindex="1">
                </div>
            </li>
            <li id="field_1_1" class="gfield">
                <label class="gfield_label" for="input_1_1">Email</label>
                <div class="ginput_container">
                    <input name="input_1" id="input_1_1" type="email" value="" class="large" tabindex="2">
                </div>
            </li>
            <li id="field_1_3" class="gfield     gform_hidden">
                <input name="input_3" id="input_1_3" type="hidden" class="gform_hidden" value="17/07/2014">
            </li>
            <li id="field_1_4" class="gfield     gform_hidden">
                <input name="input_4" id="input_1_4" type="hidden" class="gform_hidden" value="Home">
            </li>
            <li id="field_1_5" class="gfield     gform_hidden">
                <input name="input_5" id="input_1_5" type="hidden" class="gform_hidden" value="http://example.com/">
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="gform_footer top_label"> 
        <input type="submit" id="gform_submit_button_1" class="button gform_button" value="Submit" tabindex="3" onclick="if (window[ & quot; gf_submitting_1 & quot; ]){return false; }  if (!jQuery( & quot; #gform_1 & quot; )[0].checkValidity || jQuery( & quot; #gform_1 & quot; )[0].checkValidity()){window[ & quot; gf_submitting_1 & quot; ] = true; }"> 
        <input type="hidden" class="gform_hidden" name="is_submit_1" value="1"> 
        <input type="hidden" class="gform_hidden" name="gform_submit" value="1"> 
        <input type="hidden" class="gform_hidden" name="gform_unique_id" value=""> 
        <input type="hidden" class="gform_hidden" name="state_1" value="WyJbXSIsImYzNmQxM="> 
        <input type="hidden" class="gform_hidden" name="gform_target_page_number_1" id="gform_target_page_number_1" value="0"> 
        <input type="hidden" class="gform_hidden" name="gform_source_page_number_1" id="gform_source_page_number_1" value="1"> 
        <input type="hidden" name="gform_field_values" value="">
    </div>
</form>
```

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){jQuery(document).trigger('gform_post_render', [1, 1]) });
```

Answer (score 1):

To call the event only on a positive validation means you would have to call it within the validation script itself.

I'd personally get rid of the inline `onclick` method of validation and instead do that via jQuery.

```
$( "#gform_1" ).submit(function( event ) {
   // Your validation script here
});
```

This is then tidier code, and easier to read what you are doing.

You can then call a Google Analytics event as part of your validation (ie send it before a positive validation returns true, but don't call it if it returns false.)

Comment: That jQuery code is what Gravity Form Plugin puts right under the form. Its not something that I created to trigger an event.

Comment: My mistake - having read the manual - you can actually call bespoke events with trigger, so I have removed that bit from my answer.  Can you access the onclick validation code or do you need code that would work without touching that?

Comment: I would need the code because everything else is generated by the plugin. I can pass URI parameters and change some element classes but that's about it.